# Error converting data type varchar to real

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I built an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that supposed to start when I try to insert into a view of products that consists of 2 tables : `Approved_Products` and `Products`.

My point is to reroute the insert and insert the data to the `Approved_Products` table.

The data for the insert is coming from a CURSOR that holds the DATA from tuple I try to insert.

The code is as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Approval
(
    Product_ID  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Type        VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Price       REAL NOT NULL,
    Name        VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Supplier_ID VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SUPPLIERS(Supplier_ID),
    CONSTRAINT Ck_Price CHECK (Price > 0)
)

CREATE VIEW vw_ProductList 
AS
    SELECT Product_ID, Type, Name, Price, Supplier_ID, 'Approved' Approval_Status
    FROM dbo.PRODUCTS
    UNION
    SELECT Product_ID, Type, Name, Price, Supplier_ID, 'Pending Approval' Approval_Status
    FROM dbo.Product_Approval 


SELECT * FROM VW_ProductList

CREATE TRIGGER ProductApprovals
ON VW_ProductList
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE 
        @Product_ID VARCHAR(100),
        @Type varchar(100),
        @Name VARCHAR(100),
        @Price REAL,
        @Supplier_ID VARCHAR(100)   

    DECLARE CCC CURSOR
            FOR (SELECT Product_ID, Type, Name, Price, Supplier_ID FROM INSERTED)

    OPEN CCC

    FETCH NEXT FROM CCC INTO @Product_ID, @Type, @Name, @Price, @Supplier_ID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO Product_Approval 
        VALUES ('@Product_ID', '@Type', '@Name', @Price, '@Supplier_ID')
    END                 

    FETCH NEXT FROM CCC INTO @Product_ID, @Type, @Name, @Price, @Supplier_ID

    CLOSE CCC
    DEALLOCATE CCC
END
```

I try to insert

```
INSERT INTO VW_ProductList(Product_ID , Type , Name , Price , Supplier_ID) 
VALUES ('0101010' , 'Whiskey' , 'Varmunollan'  , '90' , '00000')
```

but I get an error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure ProductApprovals, Line 76
>   Error converting data type varchar to real.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the variable names.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but using a cursor here makes no sense. All you need is `INSERT INTO Product_Approval (Product_ID, Type, Name, Price, Supplier_ID) SELECT Product_ID, Type, Name, Price, Supplier_ID FROM INSERTED`. Also the `real` data type is not fit for storing prices and dealing with money. That is why `money` type exists.

Comment: will it work even if i want to enter more then 1 tuple of data? do i need a cursor for that?

Comment: i have removed the quests and it still gives me the error

Comment: Side note: I'd also **strongly recommend** not to use `REAL` for any data that's related to money. That datatype is notorious for rounding errors - you should really use `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead which doesn't have any of those issues.....

Comment: Doing this as a `CURSOR` could really grind a simple insert (with only a 1,000 or so rows) to be incredibly slow. You really should listen to the advice from @GSerg here.

Comment: Yes, it will work, and no, you don't need a cursor. Please edit your question to show your code in its current state, with the quotes removed.

Comment: The direct insert for testing probably should be: INSERT INTO VW_ProductList(Product_ID , Type , Name , Price , Supplier_ID) 
VALUES ('0101010' , 'Whiskey' , 'Varmunollan'  , 90 , '00000')

Comment: Your trigger has numerous bugs in it: 1. Infinite loop - 2nd `FETCH NEXT` should be inside while loop, 2. Variable names are enclosed in quotes - `VALUES ( '@Product_ID', '@Type' ....` , 3. No column list in `INSERT INTO Product_Approval` - this is the issue that causes the error to be returned. 4. I agree with previous posters - please remove cursor

Answer (score 1):

One should avoid inserting data without listing columns explicitly. Your error is the exact reason why.

```sql
INSERT INTO Product_Approval 
VALUES ('@Product_ID', '@Type', '@Name', @Price, '@Supplier_ID')
```

The order of columns in the table is different from the one in the INSERT statement.